# Счетчик для индексов json

Tags: python, json, for

Доброе время суток. Решил написать парсер для ускорения работы, который собирает данные в виде json с сайта поставщика и приводит в нужный мне вид. Но наткнулся на проблему в виде невозможности написания счетчика, который перебирал бы самое нижнее древо подкатегорий от 0 до количества возможных подкатегорий там. Если пишу руками циферку - все работает, если пишу счетчик - нет. При написании счетчика ругается на то что я использую лист, казалось бы используй снова enumerate, но беда в том что я уже использовал index и value оттуда, и если буду использовать вновь то пишет ошибку. Сможет кто помочь решить задачу? А то уже третий день не сплю.

```
category_id = [3, 4, 6, 18, 20]
for index, value in enumerate(category_id, start=0):
    # Выгрузка всех категорий указанных в category_id
    name = catalogData[value]['name']
    id = catalogData[value]['id']
    parentId = 0
    parsed_main_category = {
        "categoryid": id,
        "externalid": id,
        "name": name,
        "parentcategory": parentId
    }
    print(parsed_main_category)

    # Выгрузка всех подкатегорий указанных выше категорий
    for subcategories in catalogData[value]['childrens']:
        name = subcategories['name']
        id = subcategories['id']
        parentId = subcategories['parentId']
        parsed_subcategories = {
            "categoryid": id,
            "externalid": id,
            "name": name,
            "parentcategory": parentId
        }
        print(parsed_subcategories)
        # Выгрузка подкатегорий в подкатегориях
        for under_subcategories in catalogData[value]['childrens'][ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ СЧЕТЧИК]['childrens']:
            name = under_subcategories['name']
            id = under_subcategories['id']
            parentId = under_subcategories['parentId']

            parsed_under_subcategories = {
                "categoryid": id,
                "externalid": id,
                "name": name,
                "parentcategory": parentId
            }
            print(parsed_under_subcategories)
```

Вид JSON массива:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, вот кусок вашего кода:

```
for subcategories in catalogData[value]['childrens']:
    ...
    for under_subcategories in catalogData[value]['childrens'][ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖЕН БЫТЬ СЧЕТЧИК]['childrens']:
       ...
```

Внутри переменной `subcategories` уже лежит текущий элемент из списка `catalogData[value]['childrens']`, вам не нужно еще раз его по индексу получать, просто пишите так:

```
for subcategories in catalogData[value]['childrens']:
    ...
    for under_subcategories in subcategories['childrens']:
        ...
```

Если вдруг очень хочется по индексу, то нужно итерироваться по `catalogData[value]['childrens']` с `enumerate`:

```
for i, subcategories in enumerate(catalogData[value]['childrens']):
    ...
    for under_subcategories in catalogData[value]['childrens'][i]['childrens']:
        ...
```

это уже избыточно, потому что `subcategories == catalogData[value]['childrens'][i]`

Comment: Ух и правда помогло, не знаю почему я сразу не перебрал under_subcategories в subcategories['childrens']. Спасибо большое.